# WPF user control to display years and months from one total months value

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding

I have a value in a database that is the totals number of months. In my WPF UI I need to display and update this value as the number of years and the number of months. I am struggling to get the bindings to work in this control so that I can view and update this one value of total months using the two separate textboxes (years and months)

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You need two way binding, right?

Answer (score 0):

In the class that is the source of your bindings (e.g. a ViewModel) you can add two properties that calculate the two values whenever needed. For example:

```
private const int MonthsInAYear = 12; // pedagogic purposes only :)  

// This field contains the updated database value
private int _timeInMonths; 

public int TimeYears
{
    get { return _timeInMonths / MonthsInAYear; }
}
public int TimeMonths
{
    get { return _timeInMonths % MonthsInAYear; }
}
```

If you want these values to be automatically updated, make this class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for both properties whenever the value of `_timeInMonths` changes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use a converter to convert your month value to the corresponding Year and month values.Or you can do it in your viewmodel itself

Sample

```
    public class MonthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       if(((string)parameter)=="Year")
       {
           return (int)value / 12;
       }
       if (((string)parameter) == "Month")
       {
           return (int)value % 12;
       }
       return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and in your xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Height="23" Text="{Binding TotalMonths,Converter={StaticResource MonthConverter},ConverterParameter='Year',StringFormat={}{0}Years}"/>
        <TextBlock Height="23" Text="{Binding TotalMonths,Converter={StaticResource MonthConverter},ConverterParameter='Month',StringFormat={}{0}Months}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```